# If the displacement of an object is not differentiable at some point, say $x(t)=t\sin(1/t)$ at $t=0$, how is its instant $v$ defined?

Tags: kinematics, velocity, differentiation, calculus, displacement

If instant velocity at any given time $t_0$ is defined as the derivative of $x(t)$ at $t_0$, what if the derivative does not exist? How are we supposed to deal with $x(t)=|t|$ at $t=0$, or for more complex examples, how are we supposed to deal with the cases (i.e. define instant velocity at that 'bad' point) such as $x(t)=t\sin(1/t)$ at $t=0$ if we add $x(0)=0$?

Comment: What do you mean by "how are we supposed to deal with it"?

Comment: One usually considers where this expression comes from, and what it may mean in the physical situation in question.

Comment: Yes, at "reflection points", momentum is discontinuous.

Comment: I don't think the function is defined at zero (i.e. it's value is undefined).  I don't see how you can determine it's velocity at zero if it's position is not well defined.

Comment: @StephenG The OP stated to also let $x(0)=0$. I suppose the motivation comes from how $\lim_{t\to0}t\sin\left(\frac1t\right)=0$, so the function would at least be continuous.

Comment: @BioPhysicist I'm not sure we can do that for this function (equate the limit and the value of the function), but presumably a more mathematically rigorous answer exists. I'd prefer know the origin of this to talk about the physics it represent.  Generally in physics if you start hitting e.g. undefined values you're either using an inappropriate coordinate system (e.g. like in GR sometimes) or you are pushing your model outside the domain it's valid in.  Wolframalpha reports $x(0)$ as undefined but does return the limit when asked explicitly.

Comment: @StephenG You can definitely do it mathematically. It is just a piecewise function that ends up being continuous.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Well I actually meant "Is the velocity defined or not? And if it is defined, how is it defined"when I said "How are we supposed to deal with it". I'd change my post to clarify.

Comment: Since the motion described is entirely unphysical, of what use would the answer to your question be (if it had an answer)?   Physics and kinematics is not designed to describe situations that cannot exist in nature.

Comment: @DanielC in reality momentum won't be discontinuous at reflection points due to the small deformations that smoothly take the momentum from one direction to the opposite direction.

Answer (score 9):

If $x(t)$ isn't differentiable at some $t_0$, then $v(t_0)\equiv x'(t_0)$ isn't defined.  That's what it means for a function not to be differentiable.

If you argue that the instantaneous velocity of a particle should *always* be well-defined, then you're saying that the position function should be everywhere differentiable.  Similarly, if you argue that the acceleration (and via Newton's 2nd law, the net force on the particle) should always be well-defined, then you're saying that the position function should be everywhere *twice* differentiable.

Both of these requirements are perfectly reasonable physical constraints to place on the trajectories of particles.  That being said, sometimes it's convenient to put them aside in favor of an unphysical - but simpler - model.  For example, your example $x(t) = v_0 |t|$ might be a model for a ball with speed $v_0$ undergoing a perfectly elastic, *instantaneous* collision with a wall at time $t=0$.  As long as you aren't interested in the precise details of the moment of collision, this is fine.  However, if you want a more physical picture, you might consider something like $x(t) = v_0 t \cdot \tanh(t/T)$, where $T$ encodes an effective collision time (an instantaneous collision would correspond to the limit $T\rightarrow 0$).

If you do this, you get trajectories which look like this:

which correspond to velocities like this:

As you can see, as $T\rightarrow 0$ the shift from $v=-v_0$ to $v=v_0$ happens more and more sharply, but as long as $T\neq 0$ the velocity (and acceleration, and indeed all other derivatives) are always well-defined.

Of course, this is just a model I made up.  If you'd like to actually *calculate* the (physical) trajectory for a squishy elastic collision with a wall, you'd need to model the ball as an [elastic object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_elasticity), but that is a much more complex discussion.

Comment: For your ball-wall model, it looks like there is a slight attraction to the wall (or some other force causing the ball to undergo acceleration towards the wall for certain times)?

Comment: @BioPhysicist Yep - an artifact of the model I just pulled out of the air.  We could make the model significantly more physical by modeling the force as an appropriately-normalized Gaussian (as a smooth regularization of a delta function), making the position some antiderivative of $\mathrm{erf}(t/T)$.

Answer (score 1):

For the $x(t)=|t|$ case, we, physicists, say that "there's no problem!"
There is no problem differentiating $x(t)=|t|$. It's just $v(t)=\dot{x}(t)=-1+2\mathrm{H}(t)$, where $\mathrm{H}(t)$ is the Heaviside step function! Even more, the acceleration is also *well-defined*: $a(t)=\ddot{x}(t)= 2\delta(t)$. No problem at all! (Sorry for mathematicians who complain about our sloppiness. Haha..) For physicists, nearly all "daily life" functions can be differentiated infinitely many times. (Different notion of "differentiability'' as compared to mathematicians.)

And here comes your interesting question: $x(t) = t \sin(1/t)$. In this case, an infinite number of oscillations occur within finite time! In my personal *physics-oriented* viewpoint, this will be related to the interesting physics of *supertask*. You may find it intriguing to have a look at this link: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/spacetime-supertasks/

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question on how we deal with them is that we don't deal with the, they are unphysical since they cannot arise in any actual physical scenario. As other answers have noted, however, they may be useful to apply in intervals in which the position is defined.

It is also worth noting which force those position functions would they arise from Newton's second law. For example, your function $x(t)=t\sin(1/t)$ arises from the force $F=-Kx/t^{4}$ (constant added for dimensional reasons), which since energy is not conserved, the force is time dependent, may be useful to describe a specific type of open system, one which interacts with exterior matter, in the differentiable intervals.